# How can i create a single table from a Given database schema?

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms, create-table

The table staff itself consists of primary and foreign keys

I've been using this query statement

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF (
  STAFF_ID number,
  STAFF_NAME varchar(30),
  DEPARTMENT_ID number,
  PRIMARY KEY(STAFF_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(DEPARTMENT_ID) references DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID))
);
```

I've written this and getting an "object staff doesn't exist error" along with an "missing or invalid option". The respective codes are `ORA 04043 AND ORA 00922.`

This is the image of database schema:

[image: This is the image of database schema]

Comment: Does `DEPARTMENT` table exist?

Comment: By the way, the table creation syntax has an extra parenthesis.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring a foreign key, then definitely that table must exist before you create the child table. In your case Department table must exist before you create Staff table. As a best practice, it is always a good idea to provide constraint names for primary as well as foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
   department_id             NUMBER,
   department_name           VARCHAR2 (30),
   department_block_number   NUMBER,
   CONSTRAINT department_pk PRIMARY KEY (department_id)
);


CREATE TABLE staff
(
   staff_id        NUMBER,
   staff_name      VARCHAR (30),
   department_id   NUMBER,
   CONSTRAINT staff_pk PRIMARY KEY (staff_id),
   CONSTRAINT department_fk FOREIGN KEY
      (department_id)
       REFERENCES department (department_id)
);
```